# POST Request using .Net Core 3.1 and HTTP Request of Power Automate

Tags: c#, json.net, httprequest, asp.net-core-3.1, power-automate

I'm having a problem is sending a parameter on a post request from Power Automate using .Net Core 3.1 MVC. I created a simple person application that has parameters Name and Age, then a View has a button that when you click it send a reply to a POST request provided by Power Automate HTTP Request and I will receive an email with the Name and Age that I set to the person model. But every time I received an email it has an empty Name and Age. to provide some details below is my source code:

Index.cshtml

```
<a asp-controller="Test" asp-action="SendNameAge" class="btn btn-success" >Json Trigger</a>
```

Success.cshtml

```
<p>success request</p>
```

Failed.cshtml

```
<p>Failed request</p>
```

Model.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication.Model
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

TestController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WebApplication.Model;
using WebApplication.Utility;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Success()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Failed()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> SendNameAge()
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                Person person = new Person
                {
                    Name = "Juan Dela Cruz",
                    Age = 32
                };

                client.BaseAddress = new Uri(SD.ApiUri);
                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(SD.ApiUri, person);

                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Success), Json(response));
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Failed), Json(response));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then here is the email I receive when I click the button, and also the email I should receive with parameters but I just use a Postman for testing.

**Email From .Net Core**
[image: Email receive from .Net Core]

**Email using Postman**
[image: Email receive using Postman]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting your Person model to JSON and just use simple PostAsync

```
Person person = new Person
{
    Name = "Juan Dela Cruz",
    Age = 32
};
var personJSON = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(person);
var buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(personJSON);
var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

var response = await client.PostAsync(SD.ApiUri, byteContent);
```